# How to copy hexstring pointer containing \x00 to another pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, null

How can I make a copy of a pointer containing null without using array?

```
int main(void) {
    char *pt1 = "\x31\x00\x00\x00\x35";
    char *pt2;
    pt2 = pt1;
}
```

When I was debugging it, the output will show only the value before the first \x00 which is only "1" or in hex "\x31" and the rest is missing.

Is this supposed to happen?
Is this problem related to the C / GNU version that I was using?
Is there any workaround for this problem?

My reason for asking is that, in our embedded SDK there is this struct that contains only some int and char pointer, not an array. and this pointer must contain some string that will be containing a '\x00' char.

Comment: A string in c is terminated with the NUL character (0). It's impossible to have a string that _contains_ such a character, since this marks the end of the string. If you're working with arbitrary binary data, recommend changing your data pointers to `unsigned char*` and don't use any string functions (use `memcpy` and `memcmp` instead of `strcpy` and `strcmp`, for instance).

Comment: You are not performing a copy, but just assigning to a pointer the same buffer pointed by pt1. So, pt2 will actually contain last '5' char; you can't just see it with a simple printf because of those early terminators (as brilliantly exlpained above by @yano).

Comment: When you have a  'char *' point, you can use it as as string (with the NUL char terminating the string), or you can use it as array 'p[i]' to access any char, even the one located after the NUL char.

Comment: If the embedded `\0` does not mark the end of the "string", how do you know how long it is?  Answer: You probably have an explicit count, stored in a separate variable.  If so, and as yano suggested, use the `memcpy` function, using your count as its third argument.